# removing the frame cause by the mouse click

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to prevent this frame (as shown in the image) from appearing when a click happens in the browser ?

[image]

I have tried setting borders to none using `:focus` and `:active` in `css`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you add your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outline: 0;`. See [outline CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).